# SQL Row Data to Column Data in Join

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, ssms

Trying to wrap my tiny brain around how to write this query and I am at a loss:

Current:

[image: TABLE]

How I would like it to look:

[image]

If someone can point me to a function that could help me with this, it would be much appreciated.  I already tried using:

`max(case when ....)` and `pivot()`

which I found in other articles, but could not get them to work with my JOIN:

```
SELECT GROUP_ID, ROLE_ID, USER_ID, First_Name, Last_name, Phone
FROM GroupRoles
FULL JOIN Account
ON Account.Account_ID = GroupRoles.User_ID
```

Any help would be MUCH appreciated to at least get me pointed in the right direction...

Comment: "but could not get them to work with my JOIN" - what is the issue with `max(case ...)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it. If you need the number of roles to be flexible it would be more complicated. You would need to create your sql in a string and use `exec sp_executesql` to execute it

```
select * from
(
    select GROUP_ID, 'ROLE_' + convert(varchar, ROLE_ID) + '_' + Keys as Keys, Vals from
    (
        SELECT GROUP_ID, ROLE_ID, USER_ID, convert(varchar, First_Name) as First_Name, convert(varchar, Last_name) as Last_name, convert(varchar, Phone) as Phone
        FROM GroupRoles
        FULL JOIN Account
        ON Account.Account_ID = GroupRoles.User_ID
    ) t
    UNPIVOT  
    (
        Vals FOR Keys IN   
        (First_Name, Last_name, Phone)  
    ) AS unpvt
) AS SourceTable  
PIVOT  
(  
  MAX(Vals)  
  FOR Keys IN (
        ROLE_1_First_Name,
        ROLE_1_Last_name,
        ROLE_1_Phone,
        ROLE_2_First_Name,
        ROLE_2_Last_name,
        ROLE_2_Phone,
        ROLE_3_First_Name,
        ROLE_3_Last_name,
        ROLE_3_Phone,
        ROLE_4_First_Name,
        ROLE_4_Last_name,
        ROLE_4_Phone,
        ROLE_5_First_Name,
        ROLE_5_Last_name,
        ROLE_5_Phone
    )  
) AS PivotTable
```

Comment: SO CLOSE!  I am able to get it working WITHOUT the Phone field.  When I have the phone field in, I get the following:

"The Type of Column 'Phone' conflicts with the type of other columns specified in the UNPIVOT list."

I am thinking we have to set the output phone field to?  It's weird because it's a varchar(20), not even a special int field or anything.

Any ideas?

Comment: You would think it would just round up to the longest varchar! I added converts into the query to make them the same. I don't think there's any benefit in limiting the varchar length in the query

Comment: You are a SAINT.  Works flawlessly!  I didn't expect you to provide me the whole solution!  I did learn a lot with this query though, thanks again!

Comment: No problem. I learn a lot by working through some of these problems

Comment: Alright, I have 1 minor issue.  I want to add a new column from the "Account" table.  But when I do that, I get many null results.  I tried adding it to the "Vals FOR Keys IN"  and adding the key "_COLUMNNAME" but I get null values for everything.

Any ideas how I can add a new column from the Account table?  It doesn't exist in the GroupRoles table.

Comment: Hard to say whats wrong. If you add the new column to `... convert(varchar, Phone) as Phone, convert(varchar, newColumn) as newColumn` & `(First_Name, Last_name, Phone, newColumn)` & `ROLE_1_Phone, ROLE_1_newColumn, ROLE_2_First_Name,`. I think it should work